# Show that R/P has only two elements if $R$ is a Boolean ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a Boolean ring and $P$ be a prime ideal of $R.$ Show that $R/P$ has only two elements. Then conclude that $P$ is a maximal ideal.

I start with $x^2 =x $ for all $x$ belong to $R$. But here i have got stuck. 
Any help please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: for all $x \in R$, $x(1-x) = 0$.